# jQuery: animation gets stuck/crashes in Chrome Browser only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Here's my code which I hosted in a public folder in [dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33331786/webproto/loadingBar/index.html)

This simple animation freezes after a while when running on google chrome, I tested on 4 different browsers(Chrome, IE 9, Opera, Firefoc). The "page loading" animation runs smooth on all browsers except chrome, what might be causing this?(wont run on jsfiddle as well)

PS: It may take up to 10 - 15 secs until the animation freezes, I know this wouldn't be a problem in the application later, but I still wanna know why it does so because it doesnt on other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call infiniteLoop with a few setTimeouts. Why don't us simply use recusion for this?

EDIT: This one works as you may want it to work. It uses jQuery's step callback to calculate the percentage. if it is > 70 %, it starts the next animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var parent = $('.loadingBar').width(),
  parentWidth = parent.toString(),
  colors = ["red","blue","yellow","green"],
  idx = 0;


var extend = function(color) {
    var colorClass = '#' + color + 'Bar',
    currentIndex = parseInt($(colorClass).css('z-index')),
    afterIndex = currentIndex + 4;

var backColor = $(colorClass).css('background-color');

$(colorClass).css('z-index', afterIndex)
.animate({width:parentWidth},
    {step:function(width,tween){
        var percent = Math.round(width/parentWidth*100);
        if((typeof $(this).data("next") === "undefined" || $(this).data("next") === null) && percent >= 70){
            $(this).data("next",true);

            if(idx > colors.length-2)
                idx = 0;
            else
                idx++;
            extend(colors[idx]);
        }

    },
    duration:2000,
    complete:function(){
        $(this).data("next",null);
        $(this).css('width', '0px');
        $('.loadingBar').css('background-color', backColor);
    }
});

}

extend(colors[0]);

});
```

Comment: Ah I see.. It is indeed a simpler method, but it still doesn't explain why the animation crashes on Chrome, and not other browsers.. Have you experienced the freeze on your machine as well?

Comment: upvote for good suggestion on better solutions to the infinite loop, question remains open for correct answer..

Comment: This explains why it crashes. Have you looked into the timeline in Chrome DevTools? To me it seems like the same function is called to often the same time. That's why V8 stops the interval. I've experienced a lot of these problems with infinite loops in chrome, that's why IO allways would suggest recursion over interval, because you have to make sure, an animation is not called twice the same time at the same element.

Comment: Hmm.. Makes sense. There is however one fallback in your code tho. If you take a good look at my animation, there is a very short time where 3 animations intersect with each other(i.e. shortly before red touches the side of the browser, blue is already halfway and yellow has already started expanding). With your code, the animation would be triggered one after another. This is however not the result I want to achieve.